# OSGi - logging configuration for external jar files

Tags: logging, log4j, osgi, bundle, quartz-scheduler

I've built an OSGi application that relies on external libraries such as Quartz.
I have created separate bundle for all of these libraries but the problem is they have their own logging configuration.

So when I run my application quartz logs to the console

```
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG o.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
```

I'm a little lost in how to correctly limit or redirect the logging. I have a `log4j.xml` file in the Quartz bundle which attempts to set the logging level to error but it has no effect

```
<logger name="org.quartz">
     <level value="error" />
     <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

I've been searching for an OSGi logging strategy but am ending up more confused.

Comment: What OSGI implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Pax-Logging](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Pax+Logging) - it will handle most of the many logging frameworks.  Just make sure you don't deploy the actual log4j jar, the Pax-Logging api and implementation bundles will take care of everything for you.

You can set a default logging level, but for more detailed configuration you'll need a ConfigAdmin service as well.   See http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxlogging/Configuration